# Ubuntu Touch Music app installed in 16.04 unity 7 shows no music

Tags: unity, ubuntu-touch, 16.04, music

For some reason the music-app installed in ubuntu 16.04 desktop unity 7 shows no music even when there is music in the music directory in my home. Does it look for music somewhere else?

[image: No Music Found]

Answer (score 2):

There's a service that should be installed that scans your music and creates a library for the application to use. You can restart this service by executing the following command:

```
restart mediascanner-2.0
```

If that doesn't work or isn't valid, you may need to install the daemon:

```
sudo apt-get install mediascanner2.0
```

Comment: Also works on uTouch devices.